# How to get permission to run a google app Script from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to capture selected text in a chrome extension and put it in a Google Doc, however whenever I try to run the script with the packaged extension I get the following errors.

```
The given range does not belong to the current selection's document.

Blocked script execution in 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E23-KSMXgymTVpYVtimQHw26yrqAVYlNHUb59zcPleU/edit' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.
```

Any info on how to fix these issues would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#top_of_page),

> Scripts do not request authorization if they use only services that cannot access user data or if you access the script as a web app that runs under the script owner's user identity.

The user identity that a script runs with — and thus the data it can access — varies based on the scenario in which the script is run, as shown in the table given in [Permissions and types of scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts).

For additional information, please check solution given in this SO posts - [Running Apps Script from Chrome extension requires authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671735/running-apps-script-from-chrome-extension-requires-authorization) and [Can I execute Google Apps Script code from a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404922/can-i-execute-google-apps-script-code-from-a-chrome-extension).

Lastly, to help you troubleshoot the encountered issue, you may try to

> Look at the "Execution Transcript" under "View" in the Script Editor, immediately after receiving the error.
>
> It should show the file & line number where the exception occurred.

as given in this SO post - [How do I find the “operation's” location within the code? 'This operation is not supported from a callback function.'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733976/how-do-i-find-the-operations-location-within-the-code-this-operation-is-not)